# Powershell List Network Printers on Remote PC

Tags: powershell, printing, printers

I am trying to trouble shoot a GPO to deploy a printer and I need to see what network printers are on a remote machine for the current logged on user. When I do this

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_Printer -ComputerName PCNAME
```

I get a list of the local installed printers and when I try this

```
  Get-WMIObject Win32_Printer -ComputerName PCNAME | where{$_.Name -like “*\\*”} | select sharename,name
```

I get nothing. Any help? I am using PowerShell 4.0 so the `Get-Printer` doesn't work.

Comment: The issue is the user context you are running under as the network printers are per user. As the wmi cmdlets you run will I believe be run in the system context on the remote machine. Also `Get-Printer` is available in PowerShell 4 but requires Win8 or later, but will likewise run into this issue. Solutions for this issue that I have seen in the past have pulled the information the user registry.

Comment: If this is running as the current user in you GPO why are you specifying the `-computername`? Your where filter logic looks sounds outside of that.

Comment: are you troubleshooting this in production or a test environment?  if you are in test you could always execute the commands using the user account that should be mapping the printers, that's not really possible if your doing this in PROD with live user accounts tho.

Comment: I am troubleshooting in a production environment. The printers deploy per computer in my test environment just fine.

Comment: Get logged on user's `SID`, then get installed printers from `HKEY_USERS\SID\Printers\Connections`. Works like a charm in my production environment. You can do that remotely, of course, without even having `WinRM` enabled. @Matt I believe the GPO _installs_ the printer, OP's troubleshooting it remotely with the script.

Comment: @sodawillow Reading it again I think you are right. Remote registry needs to be running of course for that and the user needs to be loaded.... same is the case of wmi though.

Comment: You can manually load the NTUSER.DAT file of the unlogged user : ).

Answer (score 1):

I borrowed heavily from tukan's code in another thread (thanks... that code bridged a gap I had not yet been able to bridge) and modified it to my purposes.

The code below determines the logged-in user on the specified remote computer, then outputs the printers that user has listed in the Registry under HKU<SID>\Printers\Connections.

As a bonus I added a couple extra lines that output the user's currently-selected default printer.

```
#- BEGIN FUNCTION -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function remote_registry_query($target, $key)
{
   Try {
        $registry = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey("Users", $target)
        ForEach ($sub in $registry.OpenSubKey($key).GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            #This is really the list of printers
            write-output $sub
        }

  } Catch [System.Security.SecurityException] {
        "Registry - access denied $($key)"
  } Catch {
        $_.Exception.Message
  }
}
#- END FUNCTION ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


##############################
# EXECUTION STARTS HERE
##############################

# Prep variables and get information for the function call


# set the computer name
$computer = "computer_name"


# get the logged-in user of the specified computer
$user = Get-WmiObject –ComputerName $computer –Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object UserName
$UserName = $user.UserName
write-output " "
write-output " "
write-output "Logged-in user is $UserName"
write-output " "
write-output " "
write-output "Printers are:"
write-output " "

# get that user's AD object
$AdObj = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($user.UserName)

# get the SID for the user's AD Object 
$strSID = $AdObj.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])

#remote_registry_query -target $computer -key $root_key
$root_key = "$strSID\\Printers\\Connections"
remote_registry_query -target $computer -key $root_key

# get a handle to the "USERS" hive on the computer
$reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey("Users", $Computer)
$regKey = $reg.OpenSubKey("$strSID\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Windows")

# read and show the new value from the Registry for verification
$regValue = $regKey.GetValue("Device")
write-output " "
write-output " "
write-output "Default printer is $regValue"
write-output " "
write-output " "
[void](Read-Host 'Press Enter to continue…')
```